# Regex for a single space then numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this an an sql query to return just the first numbers out of a string and nothing else.  I need it to do that for the first match that starts with a space.

so

```
hello world56 12345
```

would return only `12345`

right now I get the `56`

```
SUBSTRING(s.Description, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',s.Description), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(s.Description, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',s.Description), LEN(s.Description)))-1);
```

--test

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(1000)

SET @Str  =  'ANDERSON, LEILANI M - MEDICAL  ONCOLOGY 40225   (DFCI)'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, 
       PATINDEX(' %[0-9]%',@str)+1, 
       PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',
               SUBSTRING(@str, 
                         PATINDEX(' %[0-9]%',@str)+1, 
                         LEN(@str)))-1);
```

Comment: You're not using regular expressions, you're using `LIKE` patterns.

Comment: Does SQL Server implement regular expressions? I think not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a space at the beginning of the pattern, and then add 1 to the index that it returns to get the position of the digit after the space.

```
SUBSTRING(s.Description, 
          PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',s.Description)+1, 
          PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',
                   SUBSTRING(s.Description, 
                             PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',s.Description)+1, 
                             LEN(s.Description))
                   + ' ')-1);
```

I append a space in the second `PATINDEX()` call so that it will work correctly if the number is at the end of the string.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=d87f3ed0836954bbeed10781de3356bd)

Comment: this left a blank for the string: 'ANDERSON, LEILANI M - MEDICAL  ONCOLOGY 40225   (DFCI)'

Comment: I misunderstood how `%` works in `PATINDEX. I've fixed it, and fixed a problem that happens if the number is at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following select statement with `substring`, `charindex`, and `patindex` :

```
select substring(q.str, charindex(' ',q.str)+1,len(q.str)) as "Result"
  from 
(
 select substring(Description,patindex('%[0-9]%',Description),len(Description)) str
   from tab
) q;

Result
------
12345
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/UACJEB73611)

Comment: The issue with this one is that if the string has no numbers in it it returns the string after the first space instead of blank

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack but your question depends on numbers, doesn't it?

Comment: sure. in the original query if there were no numbers in the source string I got a blank string back. For the new one looking for a leading space I get the part of the string after the space instead of a blank if the source string has no numbers.